# Android & Eclipse: Changing application API level

Tags: android, eclipse, android-api-levels

I am having some difficulty in figuring out how to change an applications API level - the only available level I can configure is level 15. This is not so good as the device I am attempting to test software is running on level 8. Does anyone know I might go about fixing this problem?

Thanks,
J

Comment: Have you tried changing `minSdkVersion` in manifest? Can you be a bit more specific please?

Comment: Have you checked your applications configured API level in the manifest file...? And if so, you can also check the Target version in Run Configurations (Run -> Run Configurations -> Target tab).

Comment: it sounds like you donT have the sdks for lover levels. Did u check what SDK you have in the ADT?

Comment: As it turns out I cannot install the missing api packages below level 15.. I am getting a "This package depends on missing SDK api platform, level X" for all levels below 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed other platform versions?

You can change the build target by right clicking the project ->Properties->Android:

Comment: It would not allow me to install the missing platforms on the first few tries. I am not sure why, but now it will allow me to do so, this should be the problem solved.

Comment: If you still have problems maybe a reinstall of the sdk from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and then adding all the versions(and maybe aditional stuff) could work.

Comment: Thanks Luksprog, I knew I had done something like that before, but my mind drew blank and updating an old project with getrotation wouldn't take until I did this.

Answer (score 2):

Your question can have multiple interpretations. Here's some hints:

- Application Build Target API Level : when you create your application, eclipse ask you that. You can build it with a certain api level. This option is choosen in eclipse direclty when you create your project. This tells your application that it may only be available to devices with this api level since it is the level that is put in minsdk. The target is in the file project.properties.
- Application MinSDK : This is the minimum version of android your application can run ( Note : It may not be the application build target level because you can create an application with target api level 15 and make it runnable with minsdk in level 7 and manage backward compatibility or avoid level 8 to 15 new features). This can be modified in your android manifest xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new site replacing https by http will not work to download
platform (it's not meant for this, we're making the UI clearer).

If you really cannot download over https using r5 (there was a bug in
r4 and before but we fixed it), go to the settings page (in the
standalone version of the SDK Updater), and check "Force https sources
to be fetch using http"

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of the "target" attribute in the project.properties(or default.properties) file.
OR 
if you use eclipse; right clic on your project ->Properties->Android->Project Build Target

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the required level 8 software is installed on your machine.
In eclipse goto Window > Android SDK Manager.
In the show column make sure that Update/New and Installed check buttons are checked.

If not installed then install the required API level. Then  on the project, goto Properties and select Android on the left pane. Select your API level and click OK.